# how can i use value of field in mongoose aggregation? (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

how can i use value of field in mongoose aggregation?

i tried with latest version of mongodb, mongoose.

```
Group.find({name:'1'},function(err,groups){
    groups.forEach(function(g){
        result=await People.countDocuments({group:g._id})
    });
});
```

I already checked that 'result' of this code is 3, 5, 2

i want to use aggregate

```
Group.aggregate()
        .project({_id:true,name:true})
        .addFields({numOfPeople: await People.countDocuments({group:this._id})});
```

output

```
[{name:'1',numOfPeople:0},
{name:'2',numOfPeople:0},
{name:'3',numOfPeople:0}]
```

expected

```
[{name:'1',numOfPeople:3},
{name:'2',numOfPeople:5},
{name:'3',numOfPeople:2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use group by

```
db.groups.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : "$name",
           numOfPeople: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
);
```